# Changing images randomly on button click and fire the corresponding listener

Tags: android, random, onclick, imageview, listener

I have a requirement that, I have 5 `ImageButtons`. I want to load Some 60 - 80 Images on these 5 `ImageButtons` randomly. How can I do that?

```
public void setRandomImages(int n){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int x = rand.nextInt(5)+1;

    switch (x) {
    case 1:
        bt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new listener());

        bt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        bt2.setOnClickListener(new listener());

        bt3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        bt3.setOnClickListener(new listener());

        bt4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bt4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        bt4.setOnClickListener(new listener());

        bt5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bt5.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        bt5.setOnClickListener(new listener());
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

Also `onclick` of the corresponding loaded image, I want to play some sound, for that I can use Handlers.

All I want to know is **How to refer the corresponding Listener to the selected Image at random.**

i.e.,

**If I select an image, I will play sound and then load different image in its place and all the above process repeats.**

I know it is all messy , but anyone who understood my requirement, suggest/help me.

Edit:

RandomImagePicker.java

```
public class RandImagePicker extends Activity {

Handler handler = new Handler();
int resId1,resId2,resId3,resId4;
List<ImageSound> ImageSoundObjs = new ArrayList<ImageSound>();
ImageView iv5;
ImageView img1,img2,img3,img4;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rand_image_picker);

    iv5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image5);

    createImageAndSoundObjects();
    showObjects();
}

private void createImageAndSoundObjects() {
    ImageSound obj;

    TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_imgs);
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= 12 ; i++) {

        obj = new ImageSound(imgs.getResourceId(i, 1));
        ImageSoundObjs.add(obj);
    }
}

private void showObjects() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
    img4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image4);

    for(int i = 0 ; i <= 12 ; i++) {
        int  n1 = rand.nextInt(12)+1;
        int  n2 = rand.nextInt(12)+1;
        int  n3 = rand.nextInt(12)+1;
        int  n4 = rand.nextInt(12)+1;

        resId1 = ImageSoundObjs.get(n1).getResourceId();
        img1.setImageResource(resId1);
        img1.setOnClickListener(new Listener());

        resId2 = ImageSoundObjs.get(n2).getResourceId();
        img2.setImageResource(resId2);
        img2.setOnClickListener(new Listener());


        resId3 = ImageSoundObjs.get(n3).getResourceId();
        img3.setImageResource(resId3);
        img3.setOnClickListener(new Listener());

        resId4 = ImageSoundObjs.get(n4).getResourceId();
        img4.setImageResource(resId4);
        img4.setOnClickListener(new Listener());
    }

}

class Listener implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                showObjects();
                iv5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 1000);

        img1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        img3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        img4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (v.getId() == R.id.image1) {
            iv5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv5.setImageResource(resId1);
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.image2) {
            iv5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv5.setImageResource(resId2);
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.image3) {
            iv5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv5.setImageResource(resId3);
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.image4) {
            iv5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv5.setImageResource(resId4);
        }

    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.rand_image_picker, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

ImageSound.java

```
public class ImageSound {
int mResourceId;
ImageSound(int i) {
    mResourceId = i;
}

public int getResourceId() {
    return mResourceId;
}
```

}

Comment: I would suggest, create a class with imagepath and sound associated with it as properties of that class. Create the object of these accordingly with proper values and create a list of these. Randomly pick items from the list using rand().

Answer (score 1):

I created a very basic example which shows you how to randomly pick the image, This can be extended by adding properties to the object as you want, like sound in your case.

Its just a quick 10 min prototype thing, check here.

https://github.com/sathvik87/RandomImage

Comment: Thanks a ton Sathvik, You helped me a lot , but my main requirement is that , I want to play a corresponding SOUND for that Image. For e.g., If I click One of the random Image, Say, Lion, I want to play "Roar of a lion" & if Cat is clicked, respective sound .... Like that.In the code you provided , It is limited to loading Images Only.I have Set Listener <Edited Above>and it is working.But How can I set That Matching Sound Please.

Comment: You can take it from there, Add another property(variable) which is a reference to sound in ImageSound class and initialize it in constructor similar to resourceId. You should be able to do it from there.